# Scheme zipper predicate function

Tags: function, scheme, predicate, zipper

I'm trying to write a predicate function that returns TRUE when a list is defined to be a zipper. A zipper is defined as a proper list where each element is a list with exactly two elements and can be any expressions.

An example being

```
(zipper? '((a 1)(b 2)))
#t
(zipper? '((a (1)) ((b) 2)))
#t
(zipper? '((a 1 2)(b 1)))
#f
```

I tried to first check if the argument list is full and return false, then check the car of the list to its length of elements, and pass the cdr of the list back though my function, but I'm having trouble getting it running.

```
(define (zipper? l)
  (if (empty? l)
    #f
  (if (> 1 (length car(l)))
    #t
  (zipper? (cdr (l))))))
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it? I'm still learning scheme.

Comment: "Association list" is the name of this data structure. A [zipper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure)) is a different beast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case, it's better to use a `cond` than a series of nested `if`s, they're causing you some trouble. And it's a good idea to extract the predicate that tests whether the current element is a "zip" into a separate procedure. Something like this:

```
(define (zip? e)
  (and (list? e)
       (= (length e) 2)))

(define (zipper? lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #t)
        ((not (zip? (car lst))) #f)
        (else (zipper? (cdr lst)))))
```

Of course, there are several other ways to solve this problem. For example, using boolean connectors instead of conditionals:

```
(define (zipper? lst)
  (or (null? lst)
      (and (zip? (car lst))
           (zipper? (cdr lst)))))
```

Or using Racket's [`andmap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._andmap%29%29) (if not available, use SRFI-1's [`every`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#every)):

```
(define (zipper? lst)
  (andmap zip? lst))
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, Scheme is a lot more flexible than I thought before.

Answer (score 1):

your parenthesis are wrong

```
(define (zipper? l)
  (if (empty? l)
    #f
  (if (> 1 (length (car l)))
    #t
  (zipper? (cdr l))))))
```

The function is always the first element in an expression, the rest are arguments. And it doesn't quite match the specification

```
(define (zipper? l)
  (if (empty? l)
    #t
    (if (not (=  2 (length (car l))))
        #f
        (zipper? (cdr l))))))
```